# How to write a post on google plus wall?

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I have developed a application using OAuth 2.0 authentication for Google+. I am able to get the user profile information, picture, comments, et c, but I'm not able to write a message or write a post on a Google+ wall.

Where do I find the correct API call for this?

Comment: Is there an API call for that?  I wasn't aware that there was.

Comment: As I wrote in your *other* question: Please take care to write properly. While we don't expect perfect English, we expect questions to not contain txtspeek such as 'u', 'r', or '2' as abbreviations for 'you', 'are' and 'too'.

Comment: Did you find any txtspeek in this Quation??

Why do you keep on commenting on this?? -J. Steen

Comment: Google plus has provided api for getting post and anther profile information but i con't find the api for posting something in google plus wall.
That why i'm asking you guys to give some details about it.

Pradeepsimha, Makoto

Answer (score 1):

Google+ currently does not provide support for writing posts on behalf of users.